# Time response of a double sided frequency response

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to learn more about fourier transforms and inverse fourier transform. For the example below, I am unable to understand the time response signal.

Here is what I am doing,

**Step 1:** I am starting in this case from the frequency domain with this signal:

[image]

**Step 2:** Next, I am doing the inverse fourier transform of the above signal and this is what I get:

[image]

I don't understand why I am seeing the second peak (highlighted in the maroon box) at the end in the time response? How could I remove the last peak?

The code I've used is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft

start_time = 0
end_time = 10
fs = 100

dt = 1/fs
t = np.arange(start_time, end_time, dt)
freqs = fft.fftfreq(len(t)) * fs

fq = list()
signal = list()
for f in freqs:
    fq += [f]
    signal += [np.sin(f) / (f)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(fq, signal)
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency in Hertz [Hz]')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency Domain (Spectrum)')

#removing contribution of f=0
signal1 = signal[1:]
ift = fft.ifft(signal1)
plt.plot(ift)
```

Comment: Thats perfectly normal. Since signal is sampled, it is impossible to tell (without other knowledge) what frequency it represents. [Take a look, here are drawn first two signals of infinite possible frequencies for a given samples](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.729.1/aliasing_signal_ambiguity_in_the_frequency_domain.html)

Comment: In your case, samples you generated could represent (around) 20Hz, 980Hz, 1020Hz, 1980Hz, and so on

Comment: would it be the right approach to take the first half of the plot and think of the other half as its mirror image?

Answer (score 0):

The discrete Fourier transform calculates the frequency-domain representation of a *periodic* signal.

If the Fourier transform is symmetric around 0 Hz, then the time domain signal consists only cosine components (no sine components), and will *also be symmetric*, centered around t=0.

So your plot is absolutely correct.  It is showing you one period of the signal, from t=0 to t=N-1.  The signal, being periodic, *repeats before and after*, so it has the same values at t=[-1, -2, -3, ...] as it does at t=[N-1, N-2, N-3, ...]